# Calculating $\int t^2/dt $?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was solving $x\cdot(\log x)^2$. I was able to do this with by-parts method, but I wanted to know if I could solve this using substitution method as well, by assuming $\log x$ as t, thus $x = 1/dt$. So, how to integrate $\int t^2/dt $? Also, in general how to integrate if $dt$ is in denominator?

Comment: dt is in denominator? Physic things! (I'm kidding LOL)

Comment: If you're integrating and you have a $\mathrm{d} t$ in the denominator, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: You were solving what?

Comment: Is that $dt$ in the denominator? If so, what does that mean? (The differential is always in the numerator). If not, what do you mean?

Comment: How if $t=\log x$ does $x=1/dt$?

Comment: Can I write all your calculus about this?

Comment: @Rammus He probably did $dt=d(\ln x)=\frac1x$ instead of the correct version $d(\ln x)=\frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: @anshabhi If you take $\ln x=t$$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{d}{dx} \ln(x)=\dfrac{dt}{dx}\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{dx}{x}=dt$$
You cannot integrate a differential which is in the denominator.

Comment: It seems to just be a shorthand for logarithmic substitution.

Comment: Why OP has got so many down votes ? He genuinely posted his attempt ,no matter what attempt is ?

Comment: @K.Dutta My thoughts exactly Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to calculate

$$\int x \log^2(x) dx$$

If you use the substitution $t=\log(x)$, you get $dt = x dx$, or $dt = e^t dx$ This gives you

$$\int t^2 e^{2t} dt$$

I don't think this integral will be much easier.

But remember, if you get $dt$ (or $dx$ or $d$whatever) in the denominator in the integral, you have probably done something wrong. (note that it is fine if you are differentiating)

Comment: Don't you mean $dt=\frac{1}{x}dx$ so $dt=\frac{1}{e^t}dx$?